# How to serialize an array of a base class filled with its subclasses to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an array of `Test` objects that contains some `TestChild` objects.

```
public class Test
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class TestChild : Test
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test[] testArray = new[]
        {
            new TestChild { SomeProperty = "test1", SomeOtherProperty = "test2" },
            new TestChild { SomeProperty = "test3", SomeOtherProperty = "test4" },
            new TestChild { SomeProperty = "test5", SomeOtherProperty = "test6" },
        };

        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml"))
            xs.Serialize(writer, testArray);
    }
}
```

I get and InvalidOperationException that says TestChild cannot be converted to Test.

This makes sense but is there a way to do it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to annotate the class so that the serializer anticipates the subclass:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TestChild))]
public class Test
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise (if using the more complex constructors for `XmlSerializer`) you need to be **very** careful to cache and re-use the serializer instance - otherwise it will haemorrhage memory (it creates an assembly each time that cannot be garbage-collected; the *simplest* constructor taking just a `Type` handles this caching for you).

Comment: Thank you! (especially for the advice on caching)

Answer (score 0):

You could specify known types by using the [proper constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae.aspx), also you are serializing a test array `Test[]` and not `Test`, hence the first argument of the constructor should be `typeof(Test[])`:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test[]), new Type[] { typeof(TestChild) });
```